# Google dictionary per language?

Tags: google-search

We are using Google translate when we are translating words/sentences into another language.

But what if I want to lookup what a word means in my own language or in English.

Is there a Google dictionary for such things?

Answer (score 1):

From Google Search:

```
define: word
```

ex: http://google.com/?q=define:+thesaurus

Comment: How do I define a swedish word?

Comment: @jon3laze: lmgtfy.com links are expressly forbidden on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary), there is a dropdown that lets you pick a language pair (source & target languages can be different) or the dictionary for a specific language (available only for a few languages) & then looks up the meaning of a submitted word.

Comment: Google Dictionary originated in its Google Translate service, and was discontinued as a separate service in August 2011, months after the answer was posted - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Dictionary  . Google Dictionary can be accessed by using the "define" operator in Google Search.

Answer (score 1):

There is an online [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/) in your language.
When I choose the "Deutsch" Wiktionary, and type in a word -- it doesn't matter if that is an English word, a Spanish word, a German word, etc. -- it gives me the definition(s) of the word I typed in German.

Wiktionary also allows you add the (by now, relatively few) words that haven't yet been added to the dictionary.